# Resolve xkeyval key from a definition

Tags: macros, xkeyval

How can I resolve an `xkeyvalue` from a definition? The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\define@key{mykeys}{foo}[foo-default]{\def\x{Key 'foo' does nothing}}
\define@key{mykeys}{bar}[bar-default]{}
\def\KEYS{foo,bar=key}

\begin{document}
\setkeys{mykeys}{\KEYS}
\end{document}
```

fails because `foo,bar=key` is not recognized as two keys, but only as one key. In other words, `xkeyval` does not recognize the comma between the keys `foo` and `bar=key`. How can I make xkeyval identify the comma correctly?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Without a default value, `foo` can't be set without a user value. So I inserted defaults for `foo` and `bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\setkeys` does not expand its second argument, but the error message does so sometimes it's puzzling.

You can define a `\setkeysexpanded` command:

```
\newcommand{\setkeysexpanded}[2]{%
  \expandafter\setkeysexpandedaux\expandafter{#2}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setkeysexpandedaux}[2]{%
  \setkeys{#2}{#1}}
```

Then

```
\setkeysexpanded{mykeys}{\KEYS}
```

will work.

The double argument switching is to ease the use of `\expandafter`.

Comment: **Thanks!** I already thought my problem had to do with expansions, but I cound not figure it out correctly. Would it also be possible to achieve this without any auxiliary commands?

Comment: @SimonReich One could redefine `\setkeys`, but I wouldn't recommend it. Better keeping the things well separated. However, `\setkeysexpanded` works also with normally specified options.

Comment: Alright, this solution works perfectly well.

Comment: @SimonReich [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

Please accept egreg's answer. Another approach is to define a special key `set list` that you then use to set a key-value list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{mykeys}{set list}{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\noexpand\XKV@setkeys[]{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}%
  \reserved@a
}
\define@key{mykeys}{foo}[foo-default]{%
  \edef\x{Key 'foo' with value '\detokenize{#1}' does nothing}%
}
\define@key{mykeys}{bar}[bar-default]{%
  \edef\x{Key 'bar' with value '\detokenize{#1}' does nothing}%
}
\def\kvlist{foo,bar=bar-value}
\setkeys{mykeys}{set list=\kvlist}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```